# How to fill out certificate fields when adding CA_Signed Certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificates

I created Web Service. I created Outbound Message. Everything works fine, while WS is hosted locally. After WS was deployed to development server, I was given an httpS url. ok. I changed OM's URL to httpS and in Remote Site setting. After this I'm having

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.pro

I found out that this is due to certificate (which I don't have in SF). So I go to browser, open my WS's URL, download certificate and tried upload it to SF.
While uploading it says

> Error: The certificate that you are uploading doesn't match the generated certificate signing request.

I started checking all fields in SF and in certificate and found out, that in certificate I have two OU fields. I tried to put one or another, I tried to put both, separated by comma - nothing helps.
Maybe I need some another kind of certificate?

Comment: In which platform your Web Service is hosted?

Comment: Are you calling the WS from Salesforce or Viceversa?

Comment: @SarojBera, Web Services are hosted on IIS. They are called FROM SF via Outbound Message. However, I have one place, where I make callout to the same WSs, which gives me the same error.

Comment: here is a [link](https://krishhari.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/making-authenticated-web-service-callouts-from-salesforce-to-ibm-cast-iron-using-sslcertificatespart-v/) describing in detail about the same issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: @SarojBera, yes, I have already check that article. I understand, that I need to add a certificate. But I can't do this. My question is, how to do this?

Comment: Somehow it started working this night without doing anything from my side. Will ask admins and I will post result here.